# Nokia Imaging SDK for Visual Basic Windows Phone 8 project?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I develop a windows phone 8 app written in visual basic. I want to integrate the Nokia Imaging SDk into my app. Is the SDK available for visual basic or only for C#???

Answer (score 1):

All .NET applications, be it C# or VB.NET or whichever language, are compiled in the same intermediary language, called CIL. Basically, if the SDK works with a C# app, it will work with a VB.NET app.